# How to inherit a python generator and overwrite __iter__

Tags: python, inheritance, generator

I want to call the mother class but I get this message :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "***test.py", line 23, in <module>
    for i in daughter:
  File "***test.py", line 18, in __iter__
    for i in super(Mother, self):
TypeError: 'super' object is not iterable
```

I think it's just about the syntax, I try to call *super(Mother, self)* without any method, just the object itself.
Here the code :

```
class Mother(object):
    def __init__(self, upperBound):
        self.upperBound = upperBound

    def __iter__(self):
        for i in range (self.upperBound):
            yield i


class Daughter(Mother):
    def __init__(self, multiplier, upperBound):
        self.multiplier = multiplier
        super(Daughter, self).__init__(upperBound)

    def __iter__(self):
        for i in super(Mother, self): # Here
            yield i * self.multiplier


daughter = Daughter(2, 4)
for i in daughter:
    print i
```

Here it's just an exemple, my purpose is to read a file and yield line by line. Then a subclass generator parse all lines (for exemple make a list from the line...).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The proxy object returned by `super()` is not iterable just because there is an `__iter__` method in the MRO. You need to look up such methods *explicitly*, as only that'll kick of a search:

```
for i in super(Daughter, self).__iter__():
    yield i * self.multiplier
```

Note that you need to use `super()` on the **current** class, not the parent.

`super()` can't directly support special methods because these are looked up directly on the type by Python, not the instance. See [*Special method lookup for new-style classes*](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-lookup-for-new-style-classes):

> For new-style classes, implicit invocations of special methods are only guaranteed to work correctly if defined on an object’s type, not in the object’s instance dictionary.

`type(super(Daughter, self))` is the `super` type object itself, and it doesn't have any special methods.

Demo:

```
>>> class Mother(object):
...     def __init__(self, upperBound):
...         self.upperBound = upperBound
...     def __iter__(self):
...         for i in range (self.upperBound):
...             yield i
...
>>> class Daughter(Mother):
...     def __init__(self, multiplier, upperBound):
...         self.multiplier = multiplier
...         super(Daughter, self).__init__(upperBound)
...     def __iter__(self):
...         for i in super(Daughter, self).__iter__():
...             yield i * self.multiplier
...
>>> daughter = Daughter(2, 4)
>>> for i in daughter:
...     print i
...
0
2
4
6
```

Comment: @hayj: ah, you are also using the wrong class; corrected.